# CSS elements layers order

Tags: css, layer

I have 2 boxes like this:

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

box2 has a border and i want to cover the top border with box1 so i use a negative margin-bottom for box1 to come down like this:

```
box1 {
background-color:white;
margin-bottom:-1px;
}

box2 {
background-color:yellow;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

it wont work however because box1 comes behind box2. What can i do to change the layers order? I cant use z-index because thats for position absolute which i cant use in this case. Is there anyway to do it with CSS only?

Thank you.

Comment: if im not mistaken,z-index will only work on elements which have a defined `position` style

Comment: I know that, what i need to know if there is an alternative for not positioned elements.

Comment: are you able to rearrange the html? switch box1 and box2 places it will automatically change their zindexing. and no, you dont have to set positioning to absolute. you can set it to relative as well, zindex will work as long as you set a value for `position` through css

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and cover/hide the border, by moving elements, simply remove the border you don't want:

```
#box2 {
    border-top-width: 0;
}
```

This approach does assume the elements have had their `margin`s adjusted so that they're next to each other, for example:

```
#box1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#box2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I cant, in fact its not a border but a box shadow. I used a border here for a more simple explanation. I MUST move the element.